# PostGIS: Cutting Holes in Self Geometry

Tags: postgresql

I have a table of geometries in PostGIS, **some of which overlap.** When I display the geometries, this has the unfortunate consequence of blending the two stacked geometries together and producing an unwanted color in my application.

How can I step over all geometries, identify all that have "children", and cut them out of the "parent"? I created a temporary column called `newgeom`, as to not clobber my real geometry (`geom`) for testing, and tried, to no avail:

```
UPDATE zones a SET newgeom = ST_Difference(b.geom, a.geom) FROM zones b WHERE ST_Contains(b.geom, a.geom) AND a.id != b.id;
```

Comment: It seems odd to tackle this at the data model layer. Can't you fix the application's rendering so higher layers occlude lower layers, instead of blending with them? It'll keep your shapes in the DB simpler, and probably therefore faster, and will mean you're not discarding information you might need later for something else. BTW, `CREATE TABLE AS ... SELECT` is handy for this kind of testing. Especially `CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE AS ...`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've already attempted to use the application's rendering so that higher layers occlude lower ones -- that was the initial plan -- but, it seems the application does not support that in my special case. For info, I'm rendering mapping tiles in TileMill - which *will* infact draw polygons atop one another correctly... the problem lies within the [compositing operations](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/comp-op/),   (similar to photoshop's blending modes) which have no concept of a z-index, and end up bleeding into one another.

Comment: Yeah, if the app has no z-index for polys, and you can't enhance the app, I can see why you're trying to do it in PostGIS instead. Glad to see you already explored the easy way.

Comment: You can use the same colors on all 'levels' on rendering app with an opacity 20%. Then when geometries overlap it just shows darker, which is usually not ugly

Comment: @Alexandros, I can't do this because, for instance, 20% yellow and 20% purple will blend to produce brown. And brown is already a reserved color for highlighting agriculture on my map. See what I mean? It's not necessarily always color x atop color x, it can be color x atop color y.

Comment: Craig Ringer is right. This is not a Postgis issue but Tilemill's. Still your "parent" solution will not work for "intersecting" but not contained geometries. Are all those geometries displayed on a single Tilemill layer? If yes, each kind of geometry should have each separate layer. I do not believe that separate layers cannot have a z-index property on a mapping app.

Comment: how about st_unaryunion(geom) as geom where st_contains(a.geom,b.geom) , that will merge two geoms as one

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve a sub-optimal solution with the help of Craig and Alexandros in the above comments.

1. Identify which polygons are children, and flag them as such:

   `UPDATE zones a SET parent = b.id FROM zones b WHERE ST_Contains(b.geom, a.geom) AND a.id != b.id;`
2. Perform two queries in TileMill for both parental, and children geometries

   **Parents**:    `(SELECT * from zones WHERE parent IS NULL)`
   **Children**:`(SELECT * from zones WHERE parent IS NOT NULL)`
3. Apply a comp-op to the parental layer only and ensure that the children geometry layer is "above" the parental one in the layers list so that it is draw on top.

Unfortunately, this is still not perfect. Children geometries still cannot have an opacity value, otherwise the parent color will blend, and cause it to take on another color.